# Figuring out The Big O Notation/Recurrence Relation From My Old Algorithm

Tags: java, recursion, big-o, recurrence

**Hi all,
I have a question about recurrence relation/ Big O notation.  I was given a homework assignment that asked me to give the Big O notation of some of my old code/ Algorithms that I came up with for previous homework assignments. Sadly, I have not yet taken a course in Finite Mathematics; so this is new to me. I managed to figure out three of the four Algorithms that I used.  However, I am stuck on the fourth algorithms. This method is a recursive method and is coded in Java. I have, really, spent hours trying to figure this out, and I’ve watched lots of videos and read lots of articles on Big O notation but sadly can’t get it. Any help would be great!!!
Here is the code:

```
ArrayList<FacebookUser> getRecommendations(FacebookUser e) {
    FacebookUser rootUser = userCallForList.get(0);


    if(rootUser.getFriends().isEmpty() || e.getFriends().isEmpty()){
        return returnHash();
    }

    for(FacebookUser hold : e.getFriends()){
        if( !hold.equals(rootUser) && addHash(hold)){
            getRecommendations(hold);   
        }
    }

    return returnHash();
}
```

**Note About the Code:**
The method takes a FacebookUser as an argument. The method returns an ArrayList that contains all of the friends of the FacebookUser that is passed into it plus the result of calling the same getRecommendations method on all of that FacebookUser’s friends. It does not add anyone to the list of recommendations if they are already on it and does not add the FacebookUser (E.I rootUser) that is calling it; As that could lead to an infinite loop. I use a HashSet as my collection and then I have to change it back to an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your code right then this isn't a traditional recurrence because n (the input size) changes on each recursive call but does not necessarily get smaller i.e. it's not a divide and conquer algorithm.

This statement

```
for(FacebookUser hold : e.getFriends()){
        if( !hold.equals(rootUser) && addHash(hold)){
            getRecommendations(hold);   
        }
    }
```

calls getRecommendations() for an unspecified number of friends which then calls it for each friend's friends. To me it seems like this method would be called for every friend in the network or every node if you think of it as a graph problem. This implies to me a running time O(k) where k = number of unique nodes reachable from the initial user by any number of edges.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply to my post; I would also agree that this is not a divide and conquer algorithm. What I am thinking now is that the Big O Notation is O(N+M) because two data sets(number of FacebookUser and the Number of Friend)  combined determines the performance. And after running this code with different amounts of FacebookUser that each had different amounts of friends.  I found out that the time complexity depended on two factors:  the number of FacebookUser involved in the recursive call and the size of each FacebookUsers Friend list.

Comment: I think it's worse than O(k) due to `returnHash()` doing a conversion from hash set to array list on every call. Depending on exactly how that conversion is being done, you could be talking O(k^2).

Comment: The Conversion is done with a for each loop, and I think it is done on every return.                                                                                                `public ArrayList<FacebookUser> returnHash() {
  ArrayList<FacebookUser> returnList = new ArrayList<FacebookUser>();

  for (FacebookUser hold : glo) {
   returnList.add(hold);
  }
  return returnList;
 }`

Comment: Taking into account now that it does seem like returnHash() takes n time. I think the time then would be O(n + m^2) where n = is the initial number of FacebookUsers and m is the AVERAGE number of friends/user?

Comment: Not Sure about `m` being the average number of friends/user. For example,  if `a, b, c, and d`  are FacebookUser  and `-->` mean they are freinds . 
`a --> b
b --> c 
c --> d
c --> b
c--> a 
d --> a
d --> b` 
Number of FacebookUser involved In Recursive Method is 4 and Total Size of all Friendis 7.  If `n` is number of FacebookUser involved and `m` is total size of all friends. However, if we do O(n+m^2)  total time complexity would be only `(4+1.75^2) = 7.0625` which does not make sense.  Sorry for bad spelling on phone..